# How to apply this code to work in ie browser (in ie not working)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

If the user checked the checkbox `unlimited_time`, and then the checkbox `not_allow_time` , and checkbox `unlimited_time` will not checked

I have tested on many browser it works ok , but it's not working on Internet Explorer.

How to do for work on ie ?

```
<input type="text" id="time" name="time"> 
<label style=" font-weight: normal;">
<input type="checkbox" id="unlimited_time" name="unlimited_time" value="Unlimited" class="checkme_time"/> Time UP
</label>
<label style=" font-weight: normal;">
<input type="checkbox" id="not_allow_time" name="not_allow_time" value="Not_allow" class="checkme_time"/> Not Guarantee
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('unlimited_time').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('not_allow_time').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('time').disabled = this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('not_allow_time').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('unlimited_time').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('time').disabled = this.checked;

};
</script>
```

Comment: "in ie browser" ? Which version?

Comment: And what is unit_time?

Comment: use radios instead....

Comment: [**The code in a jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/M3uLm/) works the same in latest Chrome and IE 10. Is there a specific IE version?

Comment: Also you might want to check that it works when you focus something else. I personally use onclick rather than onchange since some IEs do not trigger the onchange until the checkbox is blurred

Comment: for me ie 7 , 8 not work

Comment: IE debugger tools. Start Debugging. You would get some error. Share it. May be it helps.

Comment: Where is `unit_time`?? Try changing `.onchange` to `.onclick`. Let's see if it works.

Comment: sorry not have `unit_time` , i edited

Comment: Try changing `.onchange` to `.onclick`. Let's see if it works.`EDIT-` While googling around found [IE8 & IE7 onchange event is not getting triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11068216/769678), see if it helps

Comment: Popeye , thank you please ans me , i will accept your ans thank you

Comment: Interesting. Exactly the same comments I made earlier

Answer (score 1):

Change `.onchange` to `.onclick`.

More Details [IE8 & IE7 onchange event is not getting triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11068216/769678).

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comments to answer

1. what is unit_time - IE normally stops execution at the first error. If you do not have anything called id="unit_time", you need to comment out the last line in each function
2. change the `onchange` to `onclick` since some IEs do not trigger the onchange until the checkbox is blurred

[Quirks mode onchange table for checkboxes](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html)

[image]