# Onchange on radio button not working in ie7/8

Tags: javascript, html

I have few radio buttons. On click at any radio button different function calls. I don't want to call the function if radio button is already checked. To do that i used 'onchange' attribute on radio elements. But the problem is that it doesn't work in ie7. it work when it looses the focus. Is there any alternate or solution for this. i can't use jquery as well.

```
<input type="radio" onchange="test1()"/>A
<input type="radio" onchange="test2()"/>B
<input type="radio" onchange="test3()"/>C
<input type="radio" onchange="test4()"/>D
```

Comment: [This is due to a bug with IE7 and IE8's change events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html)

Comment: check this-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068196/ie8-ie7-onchange-event-is-triggered-only-after-repeated-selection

Comment: Thanx.. this works for me... I used  onclick="this.blur()" on radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to onclick event and it should work as you wish.

Comment: ONCLICK EVENT will always call the function, but i don't wan't to call the function if this is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, check output in console (F12),
you can add all function to this code

```
 <form name="myForm">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="1" />
      <input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="2" />
      <input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="3" />
 </form>
 <script>
      var rad = document.myForm.myRadios;
      var prev = null;
      for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
           rad[i].onclick = function() {
                (prev)? console.log('previous - ' + prev.value):null;
                   if(this !== prev) {
                        prev = this;
                   }
                console.log('current - ' + this.value)
           };
      }
 </script>
```