# Why `IE7 , 8` call function onchange immediately using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Why `IE7 , 8` call function onchange immediately using javascript ?

When i test on other browser `EG: firefox, chrome` , when i `checked` or `unchecked` input `type="checkbox"`. It's will be alert immediately. But on `IE7 , 8` when i `checked` or `unchecked` input `type="checkbox"`. I must to click page area again. It's will alert.

How to apply my code for `IE7 ,8` will alert immediately.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fp4sJ/819/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function number_fn()
{
    var number_val = document.getElementById('number').checked      
    alert(number_val);
}
</script>
<label style=" font-weight: normal; cursor: pointer;">
<input type="checkbox" style=" cursor: pointer; " id="number"  onchange="number_fn()" value="TICK"/> TICK 
</label>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 & IE7 onchange event is triggered only after repeated selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068196/ie8-ie7-onchange-event-is-triggered-only-after-repeated-selection)

Answer (score 1):

> This is due to a bug with IE7 and IE8's change events.

Instead, you can use the onclick event listener:

```
<input type="checkbox" style="cursor: pointer;" id="number" onclick="number_fn()" value="TICK" />
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068196/ie8-ie7-onchange-event-is-triggered-only-after-repeated-selection).

Comment: so can we say --- For checkbox event must use `onclick`----- ?

Comment: @robertwisyert I think so, try it.