# How to add/removeClass using jQuery on IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

The following code is working perfectly on all browsers as you can see on the snippet code, but on IE8, the button (link) supprimer is always disabled when I click on checkboxes, it is enabled only when I click on the other button which selects all.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this?
Thank you in advance.

```js
function suppressionMultiple() {
 var nbrChecked = function() {
  var aptitudesASupprimer = jQuery('#Aptitudes :checked').length;
  var aptitudesPresentes = jQuery('#Aptitudes input:checkbox').length;
  if (aptitudesASupprimer == 0)
   jQuery('#supprimer').removeAttr('href').removeClass("actifBtn").addClass("desactifBtn");
  else
   jQuery('#supprimer').attr('href','#').removeClass("desactifBtn").addClass("actifBtn");
 };

 nbrChecked(); 
 jQuery( "#desactifBtn input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "change", nbrChecked);
};

function selectionner() {
 jQuery('#Aptitudes input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true );
 jQuery('#supprimer').attr('href', '#').removeClass("desactifBtn").addClass("actifBtn");
};
```

```css
#selectionner {
 float: left;
}

#supprimer {
 float: right;
}

.categorieAptitudes label {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 2px;
}

#SupAptitudes {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

a.actifBtn {
 -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
 -moz-border-radius: 1px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 border: solid thin #929292;
 text-shadow: none;
 background: #F6F6F6;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 color: buttontext;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 3px 8px;
   
}

a.actifBtn:hover {
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #DDDDDD, #F6F6F6);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #DDDDDD, #F6F6F6);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #DDDDDD, #F6F6F6);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #DDDDDD, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #DDDDDD, #F6F6F6);
}

a.desactifBtn {
 -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
 -moz-border-radius: 1px;
 border-radius: 1px;
 border: solid thin #929292;
 text-shadow: none;
 background: #F6F6F6;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F6F6F6, #DDDDDD);
 color: grey;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 3px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Aptitudes" onchange="suppressionMultiple();"> 
  <div class="group">
    <div class="nomCategorie"> Réinsertion - suivi</div>
    <div class="categorieAptitudes" id="Réinsertion - suivi">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1251"><span class="item-search">Appartement pour mise en situation d'autonomie</span>
      </label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1282"><span class="item-search">Education du patient et de son entourage à domicile</span>
      </label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1293"><span class="item-search">Equipe mobile, suivi à domicile</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="SupAptitudes">
 <a class="actifBtn" id="selectionner" onclick="selectionner();">Séléctionner tout</a>
 <a class="desactifBtn" id="supprimer">Supprimer</a>
</div>
```

Comment: version note: jQuery is dropping support for IE8... and IE8 was discontinued for **years**. try to avoid that.

Comment: @Raptor it's an exigence unfortunately :(

Comment: Instead of a.actifBtn try only with actifBtn in css

Comment: @user2181397 still the same

Answer (score 1):

I think it is about the problem with change event is IE7/8. Please see
[IE8 & IE7 onchange event is triggered only after repeated selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068196/ie8-ie7-onchange-event-is-triggered-only-after-repeated-selection)

change to be onclick instead for each input

```
        <input type="checkbox" class="mCheck" value="1251"><span class="item-search">Appartement pour mise en situation d'autonomie</span>

        $(document).on('ready', function(){
        $(".mCheck" ).on("click", function(){
            suppressionMultiple();
        });
    });
    function suppressionMultiple() {
        var nbrChecked = function() {
            var aptitudesASupprimer = $('.mCheck').is(':checked');
            alert(aptitudesASupprimer);
            if (!aptitudesASupprimer){
                $('#supprimer').removeAttr('href').removeClass("actifBtn").addClass("desactifBtn");
            }
            else{
                $('#supprimer').attr('href','#').removeClass("desactifBtn").addClass("actifBtn");
            }
        };
        nbrChecked();       
    };
```

try this

Comment: I resolved it, I just changed "Aptitudes" from id to class, and instead of var aptitudesASupprimer = jQuery('#Aptitudes :checked').length; var aptitudesPresentes = jQuery('.Aptitudes input:checkbox').length; I put var aptitudesASupprimer = jQuery('.Aptitudes :checked').length; var aptitudesPresentes = jQuery('#Aptitudes input:checkbox').length; and it worked. It is weird !!

Answer (score -1):

```
var sup = document.querySelectorAll('#supprimer');
sup.className -= "classToKeep"
sup.className += " actifBtn "
```

You can use native javascript on this.

Comment: The problem is not in add/remove class exactly, because it works in the other case, but in onclick I think.

Comment: So, adding/removing class is not your question. Maybe, you can up it on plnker.

Comment: I resolved it, I just changed "Aptitudes" from id to class, and instead of `var aptitudesASupprimer = jQuery('#Aptitudes :checked').length;
  var aptitudesPresentes = jQuery('.Aptitudes input:checkbox').length;` I put `var aptitudesASupprimer = jQuery('.Aptitudes :checked').length;
  var aptitudesPresentes = jQuery('#Aptitudes input:checkbox').length;` and it worked. It is weird !!